# How can I make Vim NOT remove lines below with Ctrl and Left Arrow?

Tags: key-bindings

How can I make Vim **not** remove lines below with Ctrl and Left Arrow?

So I just found a dangerous setting with Vim on Linux.

If I press Ctrl and Left Arrow then whole rows below start vanishing. With autosave disabled this could accidentally destroy hours of work.

How do I disable this dangerous behaviour in .vimrc for example?

Comment: With autosave disabled typing ':1,$d<enter>' could also accidently destroy hours of work. What  terminal emulation do you use, and is it set correct?

Comment: But, undo? This is probably just a misconfigured escape sequence gone awry. @Luuk or `:%d`, but again, `u`...

Comment: OP, can you add the text displayed when you start vim, press i, Ctrl-V, then Ctrl-Left ?

Comment: please also show what terminal you are using and what is `$TERM` set to?

Comment: This happened for me also when I used vim under tmux. The way to fix is described here: https://superuser.com/a/402084/315705 - it worked for my case.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when using the git-bash inside the "Windows Terminal" tool. When using the git-bash standalone, everything worked fine in vim. But when using inside the Windows Terminal everything related to the ctrl key was strange. ctrl + right arrow deleted a lot of stuff, ctrl + end switched a character between upper and lower case instead of jumping to the end, etc.

Putting `set term=xterm` into my `~/.vimrc` resolved the errors. This may be not a generic solution for the issue, but there isn´t such either (as of all the many different terminals used).

As mentioned in the comments https://superuser.com/questions/401926/how-to-get-shiftarrows-and-ctrlarrows-working-in-vim-in-tmux/402084#402084 seems a nice hint either.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!